# Kotlin co-routine executes sequentially, but only on production machine

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a bunch of network requests I want to conduct in parallel.

The following pseudo code should give a good idea of what I'm doing right now:

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    buildList {
        withContext(tracer.asContextElement()) {
            items.forEach { item ->
                add(
                    async {
                        // a few IO intensive operations (i.e. network requests)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

I have tracing tools set up and locally this seems to do the job. In my production infrastructure however the async tasks execute sequentially, i.e. the second one starts immediately after the first one finishes.

I have also tried using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO.plus(tracer.asContextElement()))` but I observe no difference.

The only thing I can say is that my development machine has multiple CPU cores, and my production machine will normally have 1. Regardless, due to the IO heavy nature of these processes I doubt this is the problem. I can't really explain what is causing this, but my gut feeling is that I'm fundamentally not understanding something about how Coroutines work in Kotlin.

As to the nature of the network request in question, I'm using a third party SDK that asynchronously executes the request, and seems to use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` under the hood as an executor.

Comment: There are a few weird things in this code. But first, the elephant in the room: what is `tracer` and `asContextElement` and, more importantly, can it bring its own dispatcher in the resulting context? Is `tracer` a `ThreadLocal<*>` and `asContextElement` the [built-in thread local extension](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/as-context-element.html)?

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` should have solved your problem, hence my question

Comment: Other question: are the IO operations blocking or suspending?

Comment: @Joffrey this is part of `spring-cloud-sleuth`, it essentially allows tracing across coroutines ([source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/pull/1977/files#diff-0c2a0696798a8d326f2941244ee7f4fc2a9d28220093fdc606cfcace6fab6b19R35)). I'll try to remove it to rule out that it has something do it with it.

The IO operations will be blocking.

Comment: @Joffrey I just removed the `tracer.asContextElement()` part rule out it's causing this, and as expected removing it doesn't have any effect

Comment: You edited to add *"I'm using a third party SDK that asynchronously executes the request"* - you said IO operations were blocking. Do you convert the async calls to suspend functions using `Future.await()` or something like this? Or do you really wait for them in a blocking way - as in `Future.get()`? This is a very important piece of the puzzle

Comment: AFAIK `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` is backed by a number of threads depending on the available CPUs. This explains your issue. I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't switch dispatchers here, all those coroutines will run in the same thread - the one blocked by `runBlocking`. If the computation inside each coroutine is blocking, they will block the only thread one by one without any way to parallelize. This would explain what you're seeing (although it's strange that you don't reproduce locally).

> I have also tried using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO.plus(tracer.asContextElement()))` but I observe no difference.

Your fix should work, unless the IO you're performing is actually managing threads itself and also confining the execution to a single thread no matter where it's called from. Maybe you should look into the actual IO then.

EDIT: you mentioned that you perform the IO operations via a third party SDK that uses the common `ForkJoinPool` - this one is backed by a single thread on a single-CPU machine, so this explains why the calls aren't parallelized in your single-CPU production machine. The only options to fix that would be:

1. check whether the SDK you're using allows to customize the backing pool of threads
2. customize the size of the ForkJoinPool using the JVM property `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism`
3. use another SDK :)

You *still* need to customize the dispatcher in addition to that if you're calling the library in a blocking way, but not if you're converting their async tasks into suspensions using `Future.await()` or similar.

---

Now, a few other things to note in this code:

- you don't need `buildList { .. }`, you can just use `map { thing }` instead of `forEach { add(thing) }` and you'll get the resulting list as a return value (it also works across `withContext`, because it returns the lambda result)
- `withContext` actually waits for all child coroutines to finish, so `awaitAll()` is misplaced here (it should rather be *inside* `withContext`)
- actually, you probably don't need `withContext` at all, you can pass the custom context directly to `runBlocking`, unless you have other things in `runBlocking` that you don't want to run in this context
- (optional) if the IO computations don't return results, you don't need `awaitAll` at all, and you could just use `launch` instead.

Assuming you do need the result, so ignoring the last point, your current code (with dispatcher fix) could be rewritten to:

```kotlin
val results = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO + tracer.asContextElement()) {
    items.map { item ->
        async {
            performIO(item)
        }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

Otherwise:

```kotlin
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO + tracer.asContextElement()) {
    items.map { item ->
        launch {
            performIO(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Your pointers make total sense, and am going to apply them, however, these should not have caused the behavior I'm seeing, right?

By the way, I was under the impression that when using `withContext(tracer.asContextElement())`, `Dispatchers.Default` is used for any async/launch, as the docs for Default state: "The default CoroutineDispatcher that is used by all standard builders like launch, async, etc. if no dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor is specified in their context.". Also added some context about the network request in question to OP.

Comment: *the docs for Default state: ...* - the thing is, there *is* a dispatcher in the context in your case, because part of the context is inherited from `runBlocking`'s scope, which provides a special dispatcher that runs coroutines in an event loop backed by thread that it's blocking

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I just arrived at the same conclusion that ForkJoinPool will effectively be single threaded on 1 CPU devices. I upgraded my instance to 4 CPU to confirm this and indeed now it works fine.. Thanks for your help! Luckily the SDK allows to pass a custom executor service

Comment: just to be complete: the third party SDK returns a completable future that I call `.get()` on. In addition. this is just 1 of the requests I'm doing in that `launch` block so I think I still need the custom dispatcher

Comment: I see. Then I advise you to add a dependency on [kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) so you can use `await()` on the futures (which is suspending instead of the blocking `get()`). You might not need the custom dispatcher if you only use non-blocking calls via these `await()`